# Getting data from Firebase RTDB and Storage

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am using firebase for both hosting and data storage in an ecommerce site.  Each product has text data that I store in the RTDB and images that I store in the Storage Bucket.  Right now when I acess a product on the profile page, I have to make two calls, one to the RTDB and the other to the Storage Bucket.  Is there a way I can make just one network call and retrieve both?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. The database and storage use separate APIs, there is no way to retrieve both with a single request. I'm not even sure how that would be possible for them to implement.

However there might be a workaround if you *really, really* need to do everything in a single API request. Since RTDB entires are strings, it's possible to encode and image as a base64 encoded string or data URI and save it to the database that way. Then when you access the RTDB you would decode the string back into an image. I believe there is a 10mb limit for each RTDB entry but that probably wouldn't be a problem. The bigger challenge is migrating all of your images from the storage bucket to the RTDB and rewriting your app to do everything through the RTDB without even touching the storage bucket.

Comment: While this is technically possible (and was in fact what we recommended prior to the introduction of Firebase Storage), I strongly recommend incurring the network overhead of two requests. Files in Storage are easily cacheable so often you won't end up making two requests, and it's far cheaper to store and serve images in Storage than in the DB. Depending on what data you're storing, you can also keep some amount of data in custom metadata on an object (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata)

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Agreed, he should just use the storage bucket unless there's a *really* compelling reason not to.